# Program crashing when sending struct array

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm having a headache here trying to solve this. The thing is, I'm trying to initialize a `struct array` by sending its address from the `main()` function to its specific function (in which initialize it). But when I run it, it just crashes all the time. But, the program goes until that flag over there! Please help me out

ps:

The error message says:

> 45 [Warning] passing argument 1 of 'initfunc' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

```
typedef struct{
   int code, year, rentstate;
   char type[50];
   float price;
}CAR;

void initfunc(CAR *car[]){
    int i;

    printf("flag ok");
    for(i=0;i<50;i++)           
    {
        car[i]->code = 0;  
        printf("initializing...");
    }
    getch();
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])              
{
    int opt, a=0;
    CAR car[50];

    initfunc(car);
```

Comment: The function expects an array of pointers, you're passing an array of structures.

Comment: You can't see the obvious difference between `CAR car[50]` and `CAR *car[]`?

Comment: @Barmar • quick on the draw!  The OP's bug reminded me of Gimpel Software Bug of the Month.

Comment: I want to edit these structs values by accessing its address using pointers, I don't want to create another copy of it and edit like that. I just wanted to edit the original content by sending its address by parameter and receiving it right in that another function with a pointer.  Do you understand me?

Comment: @Barmar, I had learned that when we are passing an array by reference, we don't need to put those ''[ ]'', because the array itself indicates an address to the memory. Am I wrong?  that's why I had written like: zerafunc(carro);  in the main

Comment: You don't need to put the brackets when you call the function, you need to put them in the function declaration.

Comment: The function declaration should be either `void initfunc(CAR car[])` or `void initfunc(CAR *car)`. You combined them and that's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`CAR *car[]` 
means array of `CAR` pointers.

You want to send `CAR car[]` array of structure `CAR`.

Also as you pass the array of `CAR` you can access it like this `car[i].code` or `car[i].year` etc.

You would have to access `code` like it, if it was a `CAR*` not `CAR`.

For example:

```
CAR *car = malloc( sizeof *car);
...
(*car).code = //..
equivalently

car->code = //...
```

#### In your case the code would be

```
void initfunc(CAR car[]){ // void initfunc(CAR *car)

    printf("flag ok");

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 50; i++)           
    {
        car[i].code = 0;  
        printf("initializing...");
    }
    getch();
}
```

OP asked why changing the array to the called function changes the array in `main()`?

Since we are actually passing pointer to the original array, change in the called function modifies the original array. <sup>In C, except for a few special cases, an array reference always "decays" to a pointer to the first element of the array.</sup>

In `C` everything is pass-by-value. So the pointer variable that we see in called function contains the copy of the address. Any changes made to the array elements (by de-referencing the pointer) do affect the original array, [since only the array address is copied (not the array elements themselves)].

Simply put, here you pass the address of the 0-th element of the array and then that is accessed. That's why the change is reflected because you are accessing the original elements via pointer, not the copies of them.

Comment: @Barmar.: Edited and explained when users way of accessing would be right

Comment: @coderredoc, but that's what I did right there!
 car[i]->code = 0;

Comment: @Loechel.: you passed wrong parameter. Thats where it went wrong. You are callign it with `structure array` not with `array of pointers`

Comment: @Loechel.: The second example shows it all for you...you can check it out

Comment: @coderredoc I did as the second example and I am still thinking that by using that way, I'm not editing the original struct anymore, but creating a copy of the original and editing this copy of it.

Comment: @Loechel.: This question answers the question you faced earlier. You can try to debug it or after enough trying you can ask for help. This is working in the case you pass an array of `Car`'s even if it is something which you have copied in `main()`. Obviously now that you ask..it can be of lot of problems ..maybe you are copying wrong or passing it wrong again,

Comment: @coderredoc I don't know why this code is working. I thought that only with pointers we could alter stuff from its original address. I had thought that without using the pointers we would end up creating copies of the variables (structs in my case) and we wouldn't be able to return the values again to the main function...

Comment: @Loechel.: Yes you are modifying in the actual locations..thats why.

Comment: @coderredoc without using pointers? Is this because arrays are all addresses for itself?

Comment: @Loechel.: You are basically passing the address of the `0th` element,,, and that is being accessed and modified. So the change is not to the local poointer variables but rather the changes are made to the elements that it points to...

Comment: Now I think I understand sir. Thank you very much. What a practical world that we live in, where people can help each other online!

Answer (score 0):

I just tried like this:

```
    typedef struct{
       int code, year, rentstate;
       char type[50];
       float price;
    }CAR;

    void initfunc(CAR car[]){
        int i;

        printf("flag ok");
        for(i=0;i<50;i++)           
        {
            car[i].code = 0;  
            printf("initializing...");
        }
        getch();
    }

    int main(int argc, char const *argv[])              
    {
        int opt, a=0,i ;
        CAR car[50];

        for(i=0;i<50;i++){. 

            car[i].code = -1;
            printf("%d", car[i].code);
        }// RECEIVING -1 JUST TO TEST IF IT REALLY CHANGES AFTER I CALL THE FUNCTION TO INITIALIZE


        printf("\n\n");
        initfunc(car);      //HERE WE'RE SUPPOSED TO INITIALIZE 
        printf("\n\n");


        for(i=0;i<50;i++){
            printf("%d", car[i].code); 
        }
        printf("\n\n");  // OMG THIS CANT HAPPEN, WHY IS THIS EVEN HAPPENING? IM NOT EVEN USING POINTERS!


        getch();
```